# AUCTeX environment templates not working with nonstandard document classes

Tags: auctex, auto-completion

In AUCTeX the environment template (LaTeX-environment, bound to C-c C-e) tool is very useful, but it seems to not work with many (possibly all?) non-standard document classes - for me it doesn't work with memoir and revtex which are the classes I use the most. In these cases the function doesn't prompt for the label or caption and inserts the environment bare. Is there a way to turn on the templates for all document classes?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Are you talking about a `figure`-environment?  If so, I can't reproduce what you describe.  `figure`-environment as example is defined in `latex.el` and should always be available.  But you are right, AUCTeX doesn't have specific support for revtex and memoir.

Answer (score 2):

AUCTeX's `latex.el` caters support for vanilla LaTeX macros and environments.  Support for additional packages and classes are provided by respective AUCTeX style files.  AUCTeX now has a style file [`revtex4-2.el`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/plain/style/revtex4-2.el?id=aa85918447ddcd3053c3e3af09ff87537085c049) in order to support REVTeX and will be available to you with next release.